# Change all black paths to transparent pixels in Adobe Illustrator 5.1

Tags: vector, svg, adobe, photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to download some icons from http://game-icons.net/ and I need all black pixels to be transparent. All the techniques I've found on google have not worked, they have only turned them white.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Am I missing something?  Assuming you are using the SVG versions, why can't you just select the black rectangle and delete it?

Assuming for the moment you are correct, and perhaps it is some issue with importing the SVG into AI, it is easy enough to do it manually in a text editor.

Here are the contents of the "electric.svg" icon file:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path d="m0,0h512v512h-512z"/>
<g transform="matrix(15 0 0 15 -5924 -6649.4327)">
<use width="744.094" height="1052.362" transform="translate(432 440.36218)"/>
</g>
<g fill="#fff" transform="matrix(-3.75 0 0 3.75 2295.9997 -3330.35765)">
<path d="m512,944.3622 32,0 0-52 32,76-32,0 0,52z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Hp8dT/

There is a `<g>` and a `<use>` in there that are not doing anything, so you could get rid of them if you like.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path d="m0,0h512v512h-512z"/>
<g fill="#fff" transform="matrix(-3.75 0 0 3.75 2295.9997 -3330.35765)">
<path d="m512,944.3622 32,0 0-52 32,76-32,0 0,52z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Hp8dT/1/

The first `<path>` element is the one that is creating the black background, so just delete it.  But in order for the lightning symbol (which is currently white) to be visible, we will need to change its colour.  We'll use red.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
<g fill="red" transform="matrix(-3.75 0 0 3.75 2295.9997 -3330.35765)">
<path d="m512,944.3622 32,0 0-52 32,76-32,0 0,52z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Hp8dT/2/